# Angular Material md-tooltip doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am using angular material in my application and i am trying to implement the tooltip on a icon. when the user hover on the icon i want to show the text. i have implemented the following and it works fine in Google chrome, Safari etc.

**CODE**

```
    <i class="icon icon-sm icon-recent"><md-tooltip md-visible="$ctrl.recentApp.showTooltip" >Recent</md-tooltip></i>

     $ctrl.recentApp = {showTooltip: false,tooltipDirection: ''};
```

However it doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox. I have noticed that even in the angular material demo page for tooltip doesn't work in Firefox. Is there any solution for this.

Comment: it will be bit laggy in firefox but certainly it works.

Comment: It's only a issue if you have  used layout="row" or layout="column" or both together somewhere on the top of your html.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue in Firefox. Can you please try the following snippet?

```
<i class="icon icon-sm icon-recent"  ng-mouseenter="$ctrl.recentApp.showTooltip" ng-mouseleave="!$ctrl.recentApp.showTooltip"><md-tooltip md-visible="$ctrl.recentApp.showTooltip" >Recent</md-tooltip></i>

$ctrl.recentApp = {showTooltip: false,tooltipDirection: ''};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you put your working code in a fiddle and share me the link to debug?